# Ubercart: maintaining cart content after user login

Tags: 6, ubercart

I have a Ubercart site where the user can add items to cart even if it is not logged in: the problem is that when he logs in the cart is emptied and he has to refill it.

Is there a way to save the cart for the anonymous user and, when he logs in, to retrieve the cart content?

Comment: Have you find the issue with your code ?

Comment: i'm having the same problem. what was your solution?

Comment: I would also like to know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The feature looking for is default ubercart behavior. You may have missed with some of your custom code may be with `hook_user` Check that to see what happens and try disable any custom modules.